# How to list dependencies with cabal like "stack ls dependencies" does it

Tags: haskell, cabal

I used `stack ls dependencies` to list dependencies and licenses in my application. Now, after switch to `cabal` I tried:

- `cabal list ...`
- `cabal exec ghc-pkg list ...`
- `cabal exec ghc-pkg list info ...`
- `cabal exec ghc-pkg list -- --package-db=dist-newstyle/packagedb/ghc-9.2.3 ...`
- `cabal install --dry-run ...`
- `cabal list -v 0..3`
- `cabal`

But all attempts return dependencies that are different comparing to `stack ls dependencies`. For instance, `stack` lists 265 packages, one of them is `OneTuple`. `cabal exec ghc-pkg list` lists 37 dependencies, `cabal list` returns 17036 packages where `OneTuple` is not installed. Other attempts are worse even.

IMO `OneTuple` is transitive package, so `stack` lists it.

I found [this source](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/80429690da92c634cb129f99f1507dbc47a70d45/src/Stack/Dot.hs) and maybe `stack` does it with `createDependencyGraph` function, but I don't see how it calls `cabal`.

My question is: how to get the same result as `stack ls dependencies` with `cabal` ? Is it possible?

Comment: I believe this can be done with [*cabal-plan*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-plan), which is a separate tool.

Comment: @duplode is it possible to print them as JSON with cabal-plan (because I cannot find such option)?  What about `cabal freeze`? It looks truly (I think, still did not verify it), but I don't know the full syntax for licenses listing

Comment: On JSON, it doesn't look like the executable does that, though it might be possible to work out something with the library component. On licenses, the install must be done with with `-flicense-report` to enable the feature, and the output is Pandoc Markdown.